# Geolocation with local notification like reminder

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification, reminders

i want implement geolocation notification like the app reminders.
this is what i have already done:

**in App delegate:**

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease]; /* don't leak memeory! */
[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

**And this one in the view controller witch starts monitoring:**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location2D = mapView.region.center; 
CLRegion *regionForMonitoring = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:location2D radius:1 identifier:@"RegionIdentifier"];
[[Utils getLocationManager] startMonitoringForRegion:regionForMonitoring];
```

Now I have no idea what I have to do to fire local notifications with this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can tell you that your radius is more than likely too small to actually trigger an update. You have the radius set to 1 meter. That is going to take a location update almost too precise to register on anything other than testing coordinates you pass in.

Assuming you get a region event, I would put your local notification in the `-didEnterRegion` or `-didExitRegion` methods. You can create your notification like @Missaq said.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date]; 
NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]; 
notification.timeZone = timezone; 
notification.alertBody = @"Notification message"; 
notification.alertAction = @"Show"; 
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
[notification release]; // release if not using ARC
```

Keep in mind that you will not get your notification if your application is active. You will have to be in background mode if you want to see your notification fire. If you application is active, you are expected to present an `UIAlertView` rather than `UILocalNotification`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm digging the subject. With this approach the methode `didEnterRegion` is trigged only if your application is awake. Is it possible to have geolocalized notification even if your application is not launched ?

Comment: Those methods should be called regardless if your app is in the foreground or background. If you aren't getting those calls from the background, then your location manager controller probably isn't working right.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
```

and

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
```

delegate methods.

Comment: What i have to do in this methods?

Comment: well - create the local notifications?

Comment: like that: `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeZone* tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.timeZone = tz;
    notif.alertBody = @"Did enter Region";
    notif.alertAction = @"Show";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}`