# How to add local notification for geo-fencing in iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, geofencing

I'm trying to create an application which notifies me when i'm near some locations bus it didn't work yet here is the code i used

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
locationManager.delegate = self;

locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocationCoordinate2D loc;

loc.latitude = 30.794253 ;
loc.longitude = 31.012369 ;

[CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled];

alslamMosque =[[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:loc radius:800 identifier:@"alslam"];

[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:alslamMosque desiredAccuracy:50];

[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

and the delegates

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)managerdidEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_0)
{

    UIAlertView *alr=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Reminder didEnterRegion" 
                                  message:region.identifier delegate:nil 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];

    [alr show];

    [alr release];

} 




(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)managerdidExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_0)
{

     UIAlertView *alr=[[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:@"Reminder didExitRegion" 
                                    message:region.identifier delegate:nil 
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
     [alr show];

     [alr release];
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063627/geolocation-with-local-notification-like-reminder

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that this is 6 years old, and I found this via Google, I'll provide an answer for any other developer that's looking for a quick copy and paste solution.

I'm assuming that you've added the proper descriptions for location use in your apps info.plist and that you've implemented the proper `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods.

It's also worth your time to read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager?language=objc and also this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications?language=objc but the below code should just work given you've done the proper set up.

**Step one:**
Set up the location manager, set the delegate, and make sure we have permission to use it:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];  
[locationManager setDelegate:self];  
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];  
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];  
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];  
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

**Step 2**
Give the location manager a region to monitor

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.6099, -85.4808); // Auburn, Alabama Home of the Auburn Tigers, War Eagle!
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:center  radius:1609 identifier:@"myGeofenceId"]; // Radius is set to a be a mile, given in meters  
region.notifyOnEntry = YES; // Tell it to notify you on entry  
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

**Step 3**
Although your code creates an alert view, the question is asking for a local notification, so we'll create one and trigger it when the device enters the region. My code also sends a local notification only if the app is in the background but you can comment out the if statement if you don't want that.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {  
        // This is optional, but useful if you only want a notification if the phone is in the background.
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            [self createLocalNotificationWithDescription:@"You've entered the region!" AndId:@"Notification ID"];
        }
}  


// This just makes it a little easier and more tidy
-(void) createLocalNotificationWithDescription:(NSString *)description AndId:(NSString *)notificationID {

    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [userInfo setObject:notificationID forKey:@"notification_id"];  
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.userInfo = userInfo; // set the push id
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", description]; // Set the body of the push
    localNotification.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notification_sound_file.mp3"]; // Give it the alert sounds


    localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0]; // Fire the notification now
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;  

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; // Ask the app to send the local push
}
```

This code has been tested on Xcode 9.4.1 while targeting iOS 9. It worked using the Simulator, an iPhone 5 on iOS 9 and an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11.3.1.