# How to use Geo-fencing methods in background

Tags: ios, core-location, geofencing

I'm trying to make an application which notifies the user when he enters  certain region. I did it when the application is active but I don't know how to make it in background. Could any one help me?
here is the code I've used:

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
locationManager.delegate = self;

locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;


[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

if ([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] && [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled])
{ 

     loc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.794686, 31.012309);
     alslamMosque =[[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:loc radius:10 identifier:@"alslam"];

     CLLocationAccuracy acc = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:alslamMosque desiredAccuracy:acc];
     [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{ 
    UIAlertView *alr=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"you've enterd region and you are %f meters from",dd]  
                                            message:region.identifier delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];

    [alr show];

    [alr release];
    NSLog(@"enter region");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct link on stack on exactly what you are looking for:

[Geolocation with local notification like reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063627/geolocation-with-local-notification-like-reminder)

snip>

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date]; 
NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]; 
notification.timeZone = timezone; 
notification.alertBody = @"Notification message"; 
notification.alertAction = @"Show"; 
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
[notification release]; // release if not using ARC
```

After that go ahead and make sure you handle the notification in your App Delegate